# Filtering data from a GPS module

Tags: php, gps

I'm facing a problems here. This is the data that I've received from my GPS module:

> GSr,011412001293574,2,1,00,,1,090211,062123,E11150.6772,N0218.8778,0,0.33,348,2,0.0,66*5e!

First: I need to get the values behind E and N

Second: The values of E and N are not really correct. The values should be E111.5067 and N2.1887.

So do you have any idea how to filter all this raw data and store it inside a variable in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do well to look at a spec sheet for your GPS device's message format. A quick Google around shows that this is probably a TR-600 format 0 message string. It appears that the Easting and Northing are given in degrees and minutes, in the form:

```
(N/S/E/W)dddmm.mmmm
```

That is, `E11150.6772` probably means:

```
East 111deg 50.6722'
```

To store them in a PHP variable, use [`explode`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to break the string up with the comma delimiter and process accordingly.

Comment: HI Hamish. Thx for replying me.

Comment: You probably just need to convert DMS to decimal degress - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion